# Setting session or partition in BrowserWindow / Webpreferences not working

Tags: electron

I am trying to save cookies to a named session.  The cookies are saved in session.defaultSession and get() does return them.

Here I'm attempting to set the partition

```
mainSession = session.fromPartition("persist:myapi");
```

Then this function when app.on('ready') is event.

```
const createMainWindow = () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      webviewTag: true,
      //session: mainSession,
      partition: mainSession
    },
    .....
  });
```

Later after response received I check mainSession and it is empty {}.

Using v 7.1.11

Perhaps the problem is related to my cookie.  My electron browserWindow.loadUrl is a local html file.  It presents a log in screen to an API.   The cookie is returned from the API and while it shows up in session.defaultSession it does not show in devtools (like a typical cookie would in a browser).

Comment: I was researching for another issue and I happened across your question. I am not sure if your trouble is due to local file or another reason but there seems to be an issue in your cord. In the mainWindow, the setting partition should be a string; the partition name. It shouldn't be a session object.